# Auto Fill Forms For All Major Browsers

Tags: linux, webserver, database, forms, webforms

I am building a form hosted on my server.  I want to save the user as many keystrokes as possible since this is form with many fields.

Is there an autofill forms for other major browsers like Safari, Firefox, and Edge? Like there is for Chrome? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142893

Answer (score 1):

on Firefox, I use the extension "Autofill"
when you fill out a form, invoke it from the toolbar, it will learn the answers you put in the form and generate a "rule"  You can give that set of answers or rule a name to use it next time.

Comment: Thanks.  So this is for a consumer.  I am creating a form and want the fields automatically filled in for the user of my form hosted on my webpage.  Is this useful for my use case?

Comment: well no, as the extension requires a positive action from the user; system can't invoke it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Windows and macOS support the autofill forms feature in their own web browsers, but this feature is not as well supported outside of their walled gardens.

You can set up **Edge** autofill settings the way you want to enter your name, address, and other information in forms online. With this data, Edge autofills forms quickly and easily.

To manage Microsoft Edge autofill settings <sup>[source](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-change-microsoft-edge-settings-for-autofill-4782136)</sup>

1. Open Edge and select the three-dot menu in the upper-right corner of the browser window.
2. Select *Settings* from the dropdown menu.
3. Select *Profiles* in the left pane of the Settings window.
4. Select *Addresses and more* in the *Profile* section.
5. Select the *Save and fill addresses* toggle to enable it, then select *Add address*.
6. Enter the address you want to use to autofill forms and select *Save*.

In the **Safari** app on a Mac, use AutoFill preferences to fill in contact information, user names and passwords, credit card information, and other forms on webpages. To change these preferences, choose *Safari* -> *Preferences*, then click *AutoFill*. Complete forms with information from any contact card in Contacts.

**Firefox** does not have true autofill forms feature. The [address autofill](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/Features/Form_Autofill#Feature_Availability) feature is currently only available for en-US Firefox releases, for users located in the US. For users not located in the US there is a choice of several autofill forms add-ons, however these add-ons are not actively monitored for security by Mozilla.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  tremendous value here.  What do you mean by "walled gardens"?  You have outlined from the consumers point of view to enable auto fill forms.  Not sure how many if any at all would actually do this.  I am thinking of this from the perspective of collecting the data from the user.  I want to save the user key strokes.  Example they land on this page and their postal code is already filled out https://thepowerhousemethod.org/register2.html

Comment: A walled garden is a strategy used by some operating system vendors to build a "brand identity" around their operating system, e.g. a specific feature only works on "our web browser", but it doesn't work on "our competitors' web browsers". So if you are using Windows you'll also buy a Microsoft mouse, a Microsoft keyboard, MS Office, an Xbox, etc. thereby locking yourself into the Windows ecosystem. It's not just Microsoft that is marketing their own ecosystem, Amazon and other vendors are doing it too.

Comment: Eww...yeah I've been trying to eliminate these types for four years now.  I just need to eliminate Dropbox then I am 100% running on open source [code bro] So what I need to do is gamify all these options and do the best I can.  Something is better then nothing.